# How to fit multidimensional output using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying to fit OneVsAll Classification output in training data , rows of output adds upto 1 .

One possible way is to read all the rows and find which column has highest value and prepare data for training .

Eg : `y = [[0.2,0.8,0],[0,1,0],[0,0.3,0.7]]` can be reduced to `y = [b,b,c]` , considering `a,b,c` as corresponding class of the columns `0,1,2` respectively.

Is there a function in scikit-learn which helps to achieve such transformations?

Comment: Probably you meant `[a,b,c]`, or why `[0.2,0.8,0]` has same class with `[0,1,0]`?

Comment: [a,b,c] are corresonding column labels for  index 0,1,2 and in [0.2,0.8,0] since index 1 has highest value it will classify to b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import string

y = np.array([[0.2,0.8,0],[0,1,0],[0,0.3,0.7]])

def transform(y,labels):
  f = np.vectorize(lambda i : string.letters[i])
  y = f(y.argmax(axis=1)) 
  return y

y = transform(y,'abc')
```

EDIT: Using the comment by alko, I made it more general be letting the user supply the labels to the transform function.

Comment: yes it will work , but don't you think there will be a loss in information while taking only one class out of three classes  . I mean example [0.45,0.55,0] will lead to 'b'  but there is some information about 'a' which is rated very close to 'a' . Just in case you are aware of machine learning and multi-class classification, i will be glad if you can throw some light on it

Comment: You might opt to use `import string; def f(i): return string.letters[i]` to handle more dimensions.

Comment: Yes, there is a loss of information, but that is wanted here. If you have to predict, your are asked for a decision, and you use the most probable class.

Comment: You can replace the (expensive) `lambda` and `vectorize` by indexing into the array `np.array(list(string.letters))`.